# Error: sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter 'user_name'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

**Flask-SQLAlchemy Core**

I'm getting an error while binding parameters to sql query.

In this I want to bind dynamic parameters fetched from POSTMAN and return query for that specific data present in DB.

SQL query to be implemented:- SELECT id, user_name, password, email_address, dob, uid FROM user WHERE user_name = 'Pratik' and password = '123456'

NOTE: I've hashed my password at the time of creation.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    
    auth= user_schema.load(request.get_json())   #Data validated and fetched from postman
    user_name=auth['user_name']    #Data fetched from POSTMAN
    password=generate_password_hash(auth['password'], method = 'sha256')    # Data fetched from POSTMAN
    
    conn = engine.connect()
    results = conn.execute(text(f"SELECT id, user_name, password, email_address, dob, uid FROM user WHERE user_name = :user_name and password = :password",{"user_name": user_name, "password": password}))

    result_dict = [dict(u) for u in results.fetchall()]
    print (result_dict)
    return "response"
```

Comment: ...and did you try to log `user_name` to ensure it has a value? An error which states `values is required for bind parameter 'user_name` pretty much suggests that `user_name` lacks of value.

Comment: I’m getting value for user_name. I’ve done debugging I think maybe my password is hashed so query is not able to compare the values of password. I’ve tried running it without password then it was showing me data for that particular row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this I was comparing salted password with simple plain text which didn't work for me, so I fetched data using the only username and then compared password using "werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash,check_password_hash".

https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/utils/#werkzeug.security.check_password_hash